# How can I stop an onclick event from firing for parent element when child is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I'm having two issues with onclick events, they are somewhat similar so I'll ask them both here.

First:

I have a checkbox in a div. The input has an onchange function and the div has an onclick function.

```
<div onclick="doSomething()">
     <input type="checkbox" onchange="doSomethingElse()" />
</div>
```

The problem is when I check/uncheck the checkbox both doSomething() and doSomethingElse() fire. Any ideas of how to stop this from occuring? I've tried doing onchange="doSomethingElse(event)" and the in doSomethingElse(e) function I had e.stopPropagation(); and this did not work.

Second:

I have an image in a div. The div has an onclick function but the image does not. The image is, purposely, larger than the div and overflows outside the div.

```
-----------------------
|        image        |
|   ---------------   |
|   |     div     |   |
|   |             |   |
|   ---------------   |
|                     |
-----------------------
```

I only want the onclick to fire if the user clicks within the bounds of the div box. However, the onclick event also fires if you click on a part of the image that has overflowed to the outside of the div... Any ideas?

The first question is more important to me than the second. But if someone can answer both that would be awesome!

Thanks in advance for your help,
Matt

Comment: Separate this into two posts. While you asking two 'click handling' questions, the subject does not serve them both.

Answer (score 8):

For your first question: IE doesn't support `stopPropagation()`, instead you should use `e.cancelBubble = true`. Just do a function check first to find out which method you should use (`if (e.stopPropagation) {code}`).

For your second question: Maybe include a second div that handles the click event?

```
<div><img src="image.jpg"/></div>
<div style="position:absolute" onclick="doSomething();"></div>
```

and then position the second div correctly

Answer (score 5):

For your second question, you can get the coordinates of the pointer when the click event occured, and compare them to the coordinates of the div. (actual implementation depends on which js library you use)

For your first question, to stop an event from bubbling, you have to use

```
event.cancelBubble = true;
if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 3):

In your first example with a checkbox inside a div, onchange is not the same event as onclick so calling event.stopPropagation() in the onchange handler will not stop the outer onclick from firing. You need an additional onclick handler on the checkbox to prevent the click from bubbling up.

```
<div onclick="doSomething()">
     <input type="checkbox" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" onchange="doSomethingElse()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the propagation.  You can use jQuery for this: [Stopping Propagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29).

Answer (score 1):

second:

see also:

```
[img onmousedown="if (!clicking) alert('parent clicked') " ...]

[div onmousedown="clicking = true"
     onclick = " alert('child clicked") "
     onmouseup="clicking = false"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem to your first question. But instead a <div> and a checkbox it was a table. Look at my **NON WORKING** code:

```
<table>
  <tr onClick="alert('I expect this alert when Cell_1 or Cell_2 are clicked but not Cell_3')">
    <td>Cell_1</td>
    <td>Cell_2</td>
    <td onClick="alert('I expect this alert only when Cell_3 is clicked')">Cell_3</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Clicking on Cell_1 or Cell_2, my code works as I expected, but when clicking on Cell_3 not, because it showed 2 alerts.

The first one was:

*"I expect this alert only when Cell_3 is clicked"*

and the second one was:

*I expect this alert when Cell_1 or Cell_2 are clicked but not Cell_3*.

Google-ing how I could manage that, I found [this briliant](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) post on [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org).

Well, putting it simply, I could solve the puzzle this way:

```
<table>
  <tr onClick="alert('I expect this alert when Cell_1 or Cell_2 are clicked but not Cell_3')">
    <td>Cell_1</td>
    <td>Cell_2</td>
    <td onClick="Cell_3Alert(event)">Cell_3</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function Cell_3Alert(e) {
  alert('I expect this alert only when Cell_3 is clicked');

  if (!e) var e = window.event; 
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I've tested and it worked on FireFox 3.6+, IE6+ and Chrome.

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

For the second, you could put your div in front of the image, and not have the image tags inside the div.  This should give you the functionality you require.

Comment: The image has to be in the div, I've already looked at that option. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your first one is a simplification or not. If that's exactly what it is, I'd simply remove the onClick from the div altogether.

But I suspect your *actual* case is more complicated so I'm not really offering that one as an answer.

For the second case, I'd actually divide up the image into five sections and only put one of them inside the div, as follows:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                     Image part 1                     |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Image part 2 | Image part 3 (and div) | Image part 4 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                     Image part 5                     |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Kludgy, I know, but I tend to go for the simplest solutions first.

Comment: Good idea, it would definitely work. However I need to keep the image in one piece. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

For the first try also using e.preventBubble() and returning false from the handler.

For the second you can capture the click and check the target of the event. This is easiest if you use some library that normalizes events like jQuery where e.target returns you the exact element that the event was fired on. Another option is put the click handler not on the image but whatever container that you're overflowing the image on.

Answer (score 0):

As well as or as an alternatative to stopping capturing the bubbling, each of your event functions should have some code that **checks that the correct element has been clicked**, use `event.target`, or `event.scrElement` in IE, to find the clicked element.

For your second question you probably want to use an **image map**, which is the HTML provided for clicking on a particular area of a image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me it was a span tag in another span tag, for a sidebar menu. The subcategories were supposed to toggle open whenever they were clicked, but not when the contents were clicked. But looking through the properties of the 'click' event, I think I found a solution, and wrote this:

```
function sidebar_click(event)
{
    if (event.target == event.currentTarget)
        event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

It only runs if the target = currentTarget. Target is the item you click on, currentTarget is the one the event handler is linked to. If they're the same, it executes, if it's not, it doesn't.

Hope this helps.