# Disable the onclick event of a parent element

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an element with an onclick event, and another element inside it, how do I disable the onclick for the child element?

Example:
`<h3 onclick="do something"><input type="checkbox" name="child" /> text</h3>`

When you check the checkbox, the onclick event shouldn't be triggered.

Thanks.

Comment: why are you trying to do this?

Comment: What if you uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: do you want the click on 'text' to toggle the checkbox?

Comment: I'm trying to do this because <h3> is actually a drop down, and I don't want that manipulating the checkbox would trigger the dropdown.  I meant manipulating the checkbox, not just checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your handler (the "`do something`"-part of the h3-tag) can check the `tagName` of the originating element:

```
var origin = event.srcElement || event.target;
if (origin.tagName && origin.tagName.match(/h3/i)){
  // do things
} else {return true;}
```

Now for the checkbox the click handler *is* triggered, but nothing will happen. Alternatively, you could supply the h3-tag with a unique id an check the id of the clicked element.

Answer (score 9):

Javascript events are propagated bottom-up, i.e if you click on a button, all ascendants recieve the onclick event in orderly fashion, except for when one of them intercepts it via stopPropagation (or returns true, meaning i handled this)

Example :

```
<h3 onclick="do something"><input type="checkbox" name="child" onclick="return false;" /> text</h3>
```

you could also bind onclick of parent to a function :

```
function onlick_handler(e)
{
   e.stopPropagation(); //this event would propagate to parents of this object which are clicked as well
   // the rest here
}
```

Comment: The function is not stand alone, you should first bind it to the onclick event. With `jQuery, use $("h3").bind("click","onclick_handler");`

Comment: e.stopPropagation works fine, however, I didn't get the version with onclick="return false" to work as well

Answer (score 2):

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

See stopPropagation()

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26916473/2933356) I provided in a similar problem?

Above I copied my original answer:

---

I had a very similar problem to your first question. But instead a <div> and a checkbox it was a table. Look at my **NON WORKING** code:

```
<table>
  <tr onClick="alert('I expect this alert when Cell_1 or Cell_2 are clicked but not Cell_3')">
    <td>Cell_1</td>
    <td>Cell_2</td>
    <td onClick="alert('I expect this alert only when Cell_3 is clicked')">Cell_3</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Clicking on Cell_1 or Cell_2, my code works as I expected, but when clicking on Cell_3 not, because it showed 2 alerts.

The first one was:

*"I expect this alert only when Cell_3 is clicked"*

and the second one was:

*I expect this alert when Cell_1 or Cell_2 are clicked but not Cell_3*.

Google-ing how I could manage that, I found [this briliant](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) post on [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org).

Well, putting it simply, I could solve the puzzle this way:

```
<table>
  <tr onClick="alert('I expect this alert when Cell_1 or Cell_2 are clicked but not Cell_3')">
    <td>Cell_1</td>
    <td>Cell_2</td>
    <td onClick="Cell_3Alert(event)">Cell_3</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function Cell_3Alert(e) {
  alert('I expect this alert only when Cell_3 is clicked');

  if (!e) var e = window.event; 
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I've tested and it worked on FireFox 3.6+, IE6+ and Chrome.

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can have an onClick for the checkbox that sets the h3.onClick property to blank if the box is checked, and sets it to the correct function reference if it is not checked.