# My checkbox will not check when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having another problem with my table and checkboxes. I ahve gotten my javascript working which allows my checkbox to check when I click anywhere within the table cell. However, now the checkbox itself doesn't work. I have tried to solve this for over an hour now, can't find an answer anywhere. Here is my javascript and a snippet of the html it is manipulating:

```
function tdOnclick(td) {
    for(var i = 0; i < td.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if(td.childNodes[i].nodeName == "INPUT") {
            if(td.childNodes[i].checked) {
                td.childNodes[i].checked = false;
                td.style.backgroundColor = "#FAF4E3";
            } else {
                td.childNodes[i].checked = true;
                td.style.backgroundColor = "#E1E1E1";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a piece of the html for the table:

```
 <tr>
    <td><center>9:00 - 10:00</center></td>
    <td class="tdata" onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="mon09"></td>
    <td class="tdata" onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="tue09"></td>
    <td class="tdata" onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="wed09"></td>
    <td class="tdata" onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="thu09"></td>
    <td class="tdata" onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="fri09"></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: I was having some trouble originally reproducing this on jsfiddle, so here is a "working" link: http://jsfiddle.net/NKCTn/

Comment: @Tats_innit - Your solution doesn't work for me (Linux Mint, Chrome) - it doesn't seem to be calling the function at all... I added an alert http://jsfiddle.net/9tb4W/6/ , and couldn't make it happen.  Then I switched the JS into the header, and the bug reappeared http://jsfiddle.net/9tb4W/5/ .

Comment: Yeah I have tried it on jsfiddle too myself. I will post a link to where I am testing this so you can see what I mean. http://cs1.ucc.ie/~od1/project_css/

Comment: Thanks @xthexder, That's my exact problem. I have posted my working link in the comment above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, I'm going to hazard the guess that it is working.  Your click is checking the box, then the onClick event is unchecking it.  Here's an idea:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="free" value="mon09" onClick="this.checked=!this.checked;">
```

It's a bit dirty, but it sucessfully ignores the click.

Working [TinkerBin](http://tinkerbin.com/2tlPcg95).

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot. Will this eliminate my "double checking" problem?

Comment: @OisínDorgan - technically, it escalates it to a triple check - one switch from the actual click, one from the onClick of the checkbox, and one from the onClick of the td.  Like I said, it's dirty, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work another way.

Comment: Ok, would this affect a passing these checked values in a Java program that puts them into a database? I can't imagine it would? If not, I don't mind the triple click.

Comment: Err... I doubt it, if you're just using some sort of submit over the final state of the form.  If you're trying to do it live, then it might fire an onChange for each click.  (Ultimately, that would have little effect, but it could potentially slow the application down.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, not trying to do it live so I think I should be all good.

Comment: this happened to me, had the body sharing the class of the button on one of the pages

Answer (score 2):

If I was a betting man, I would guess that you are having a dual click event. One for the input and one for the parent.  essentially you are getting two clicks, effectively disabling your inputs.  Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445719/disable-the-onclick-event-of-a-parent-element).
Probability something like this would work.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="free" value="fri09" onclick="return false;" />
```

Comment: Tried it in Tinkerbin.  No dice - the change occurs before the onClick event.

Answer (score 1):

Your click is checking the checkbox as expected, then the TD click code is being called which you have toggling your checkbox back off.

Here is a jsfiddle with some comments showing what is happening. http://jsfiddle.net/NujXv/2/

You need to stop the event from bubbling up from the checkbox to the TD. I found this searching for the jquery function - http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation. I've put a commented out line in the jsfiddle that might work, but I have real jquery experience so you might have to tweak it a bit.

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem. Add event.stopPropagation() on the checkbox click event and the check works perfectly (in modal :D ).

Answer (score 1):

i was with same problem:

check if somewhere is calling "preventDefault", and check if the click function for checkboxes return true and if exist is **before** preventDefault.

i solve it with something like this:

```
$("#recordlist").click( function(e) {
     if (e.target.name == 'recordlistitem'){ // When recordlistitem is a checkbox(es)
        return true;
     }
     e.preventDefault();
     // other stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use css: pointer-events: none; on checkbox. It will prevent the initial check and uncheck, but the click still will do the work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).