# How to stop running the next function?

Tags: javascript, events

I have an event on clicking the top `<tr>` and then also an event on clicking the `tr > td > button`. When i click the `tr > td > button`, the related `onclick()` function is running but, the function related on `<tr>` is also running after previous.

Like:

```
<tr onclick="run_tr();">
    <td><input type="button" onclick="run_td();" /></td>
</tr>
```

How can i stop automatically calling the next call by clicking the button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable the onclick event of a parent element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445719/disable-the-onclick-event-of-a-parent-element)

Comment: you should avoid inline scripts

Answer (score 3):

At button `onclick` function you need to stop event bubbling:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Following to your code:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="run_td( event );" />
```

JS:

```
function run_td( event ) {
    if ( event.stopPropagation ) { 
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    event.cancelBubble = true;
    // ... rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: No, that's the wrong method... that would e.g. prevent the browser from following a link, but it does not stop event propagation.

Comment: @antyrat I am just using that. But, there is a `alert("hello");` inside the top `<tr>` onclick. Anway, this alert is just flushing one time and disappeared.

Comment: @4lvin You need to pass `event` to `onclick` property too. See my updated answer and demo on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/5AvKy/

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop the event's propagation, by using the method `e.stopPropagation()`. For more info, check out this link : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link9

Comment: For the OP: remember to use both `if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation()` and `event.cancelBubble = true` to deal with both W3C and IE event models.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention that in my answer, but it's explained in the page I linked

Comment: I am just using that. But, there is a `alert("hello");` inside the top `<tr>` onclick. Anway, this alert is just flushing one time and disappeared. Can't i totally terminate it??

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you can't use the recommended methods, here's an example:

```
<div onclick="alert('div click called');">
  Click here to see div onclick
  <button onclick="
    (event.stopPropagation && event.stopPropagation());
    event.cancelBubble = true;
    alert('stopped click');
  ">Button click but no div click</button>
</div>
```