# Stop div's onclick event effecting links within the div

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop an onclick event from firing for parent element when child is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985389/how-can-i-stop-an-onclick-event-from-firing-for-parent-element-when-child-is-cli)

I have a div with an onClick event but I don't want it to run when I click a link inside the div.
How can I stop the onClick effecting links inside the element?

```
<div onclick="dosomething();">
  <a href="mylink.com">go somewhere but don't dosomething();</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, search before posting. You are even shown a bunch of likely duplicates whilst writing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could use jQuery then,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourDivId a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

//OR without jQuery
document.getElementById("yourAnchorId").onclick = function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  //for IE window.event.cancelBubble = true
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I thought about doing it with jQuery but I kinda want to avoid it. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: ok check edited code above, hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#some_id_or_class a").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
```

Don't know how without jQuery. You would have to look for how to stop the propagation of the event in javascript.