# How can one trigger the onclick of an element without triggering the parent element onclick?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a multilayer drop down navigation bar, which, upon hover opens a menu of subcategories. Upon hovering over these subcategories a further list of subcategories is shown.

Any of the categories, subcategories, and sub-subcategories are supposed to be clickable links, which, when clicked, will show search results for the desired level of detail. i.e. food >>> mexican >>>tacos,
One can click on any of the three, to get the desired level of depth in their search.

The problem is, when i click on the subcategories, since they are nested in the parent div, i am also clicking on the parent element.

So if i have:

```
<ul>
<li onclick="queryfunction()">Category</li>
    <ul>
    <li onclick="queryfunction()">Sub-Category</li>
        <ul>
        <li onclick="queryfunction()">Sub-subCategory</li>
        </ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

Clicking on the bottom category triggers all 3 onclick events.

How can i only trigger the one event i want?

Comment: event bubbling and phasing

Comment: have look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985389/how-can-i-stop-an-onclick-event-from-firing-for-parent-element-when-child-is-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is commonly referred to as 'event bubbling'
You can use `event.stopPropagation()`
You can read up on the subject [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)
Or the near-duplicate [How to stop event bubbling on checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164213/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-on-checkbox-click)

Comment: Thank you for expanding my knowledge base!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `type` variable for `category,sub-category or sub-subcategory` with a `this` variable or can give a `class` to each level of category,
it will help you in that functions also.
like

```
<ul>
<li class="category" onclick="queryfunction(this)">Category</li>
    <ul>
    <li class="sub-category" onclick="queryfunction(this)">Sub-Category</li>
        <ul>
        <li class="sub-subcategory" onclick="queryfunction(this)">Sub-subCategory</li>
        </ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

For using `event.stopPropagation()` pass a `event` in that function will solve your problem.