# Capture click event on parent container but not child

Tags: javascript, html, css

With the following example:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="parent" onclick="alert('hello!')">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  background: pink;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

I want the `onclick` event to fire when the user clicks on the parent / blue section. But not when the user clicks on the child / pink section. Right now the event fires even when the pink is being clicked, which is of course obvious since the `.child` is a child of the parent. Is there any way to get past this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop an onclick event from firing for parent element when child is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985389/how-can-i-stop-an-onclick-event-from-firing-for-parent-element-when-child-is-cli)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method to event bubbling up to the DOM tree.

```css
.parent {
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.child {
  background: pink;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" onclick="alert('hello!')">
  <div class="child" onclick="event.stopPropagation()"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.stopPropagation()` for that event.

```css
.parent {
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.child {
  background: pink;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" onclick="alert('I am parent')">
  <div class="child" onclick="event.stopPropagation()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a copy, isnt it possible for me to type the same thing as Someone else did?

Comment: Some questions might have similar or only one answer(s)

Comment: Yes I got it but I thought about the same answer and `stopPropagation()` for a child not to fire the parent's event.