# How to click a parent element over their children

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to set an event on a few cards, but when I try to click them, the click goes inside the card, on the child elements. I solved it by setting "pointer-events: none" to the children, but I don't think is the best way.

Comment: Events in JavaScript bubbles and this is normal that event fires on children

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42022618/13712263

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to understand useCapture parameter in addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398290/unable-to-understand-usecapture-parameter-in-addeventlistener)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `event.stopPropagation` method to stop bubbling the event to the parents, but it's not a good solution if you are using a statistics service.

You can also capture the event in the parent and check if the `event.target` is the child, just `return` the click handler.